# Query optimization for multiple inner joins and sub-query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I need help regarding query optimization of the below query.

```
SELECT pr.todate , pr.descr, cmp.company_id 
FROM employee AS emp
INNER JOIN company AS cmp ON emp.emp_comp_id = cmp.company_id 
INNER JOIN profile AS pr ON emp.acca_id = pr.profile_id 
INNER JOIN acondition ON as_id = as_ac_id
WHERE as_closed = 0 
  AND (pr.ac_act_id = 20)
  AND (pr.todate = (SELECT MIN(todate) AS Expr1 
                    FROM profile pro 
                    INNER JOIN employee empl ON empl.acca_id = pro.profile_id 
                    JOIN acondition ON as_id = as_ac_id 
                    WHERE (pro.ac_act_id = 20 
                           AND empl.emp_comp_id = cmp.company_id) 
                      AND as_closed = 0))
```

Since there are duplicate joins in the main query and sub query, is there any way to remove those joins in the subquery?

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you... such as the execution plan, and table definitions, and indexes on the table. What makes you think it can be optimised?

Comment: Hi, `employee`, `company`, `profile` have `nonclustered` indexes, `acondition` has `clustered` index. Is there any way to reduce the inner joins in the sub query?

Comment: [edit] into the question please and use paste the plan to post your execution plan. Why do you want to remove the joins? Your query seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: It is kind of slow, thus I need optimization of this query. For security reasons I have used dummy tables here so may I cannot share the execution plan

Comment: Since there are duplicate joins in the  main query and sub query, so is there any way to remove those joins in the subquery?

Comment: @the_coder_guy , to be honest, StackOverflow is not really the best place to be asking for query-tuning advice. This is something that will require lots of back and forth with you, and also cover a TON of things. Your best option would be to check out the SQL Server community slack channel: `dbatools.io/slack`

Comment: Especially if you can't share any real information. Performance is the one area you can't easily create a simplified example of - you basically have to deal with the real thing.

Comment: What indexes are on those tables? Eg At a glance it looks like an index on profile with ac_act_id and todate as the key fields could be beneficial, but the order of them (and whether it's even worthwhile) would depend very much on the distribution of the data. Eg if 10% had ac_act_id = 20, and of those 30% meet your criteria for todate, I'd create a nonclustered index on ac_act_id, todate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, as you clarified, your sub-query is almost identical to your main query you might be able to use the window function [`RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as a filter condition. `RANK` assigns the same number to ties, meaning if multiple records per company match you will get them all e.g.

```
SELECT todate, descr, company_id
FROM (
    SELECT pr.todate, pr.descr, cmp.company_id
      , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cmp.company_id ORDER BY pr.todate ASC) RankNumber
    FROM employee AS emp
    INNER JOIN company AS cmp ON emp.emp_comp_id = cmp.company_id 
    INNER JOIN profile AS pr ON emp.acca_id = pr.profile_id 
    INNER JOIN acondition ON as_id = as_ac_id
    WHERE as_closed = 0 AND pr.ac_act_id = 20
) X
where RankNumber = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, This query is giving me only one result and my original query gives me around 35 results.

Comment: Hi, I tried to debug but I am not able to figure out what can be wrong in the where clause.

Comment: Previous record example :
2019-01-31 00:00:00.000 New Employee 101
2020-11-27 00:00:00.000 Old Employee  014
2020-11-27 00:00:00.000 Tenure Employee 016
2020-12-11 00:00:00.000 New Junior Employee  030
2020-11-27 00:00:00.000 Director  034
2020-12-14 00:00:00.000 Junior Manager  052
2019-02-18 00:00:00.000 Senior Manager 058

Comment: New Record output : 2019-01-31 00:00:00.000 New Employee 101

Comment: It should not be only returning the oldest record, it should be returning all the records with the matching criteria. So if I execute the original query without the 
` AND (pr.todate = (SELECT MIN(todate) AS Expr1 
                    FROM profile pro 
                    INNER JOIN employee empl ON empl.acca_id = pro.profile_id 
                    JOIN acondition ON as_id = as_ac_id 
                    WHERE (pro.ac_act_id = 20 
                           AND empl.emp_comp_id = cmp.company_id) 
                      AND as_closed = 0)) `

Comment: condition it gives me 49 records and with the confition it gives 36 records

Comment: OK try now - you can see how hard you make it for us when you don't provide a [MRE] :)

Comment: @the_coder_guy Out of interest, what was the speed improvement?

Comment: Hi @Dale K , sorry but this solution has not improved the speed, it seems 2 times slower now.

Comment: lol - thats what happens sometimes when we try and improve things. You will now need to dig in using the execution plan to find out what is taking the time.

Comment: Hi, It is giving issues on PROD and not on Dev environment, hence it is difficult to interpret that. Is there any other way to solve this query?

Comment: And also, it is giving me duplicate records if the date and description are same. @Dale K

Comment: Try changing `SELECT todate ...` to `SELECT DISTINCT todate ...`. If this is performing badly I suggest you are missing indexes. And the only way you can evaluate the performance is by inspecting the execution plan. Alternatively, use your original query, there is nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT ca.todate , pr.descr, cmp.company_id 
FROM employee AS emp
INNER JOIN company AS cmp ON emp.emp_comp_id = cmp.company_id 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP(1) pr.todate
    FROM profile pr 
    INNER JOIN acondition ON as_id = as_ac_id 
    WHERE emp.acca_id = pr.profile_id AND (pr.ac_act_id = 20) AND as_closed = 0 
    ORDER BY pr.todate ASC
) AS ca
```

Comment: Hi, in the inner join for `INNER JOIN acondition ON as_id = as_ac_id` I am getting in error as it is part of the profile table.

Comment: Hi, It is not giving me correct results, the `min (todate )` criteria is not getting applied I suppose. Thus I am getting 49 results.

Comment: @Tole1010 you made the same mistake as me, you got a single min `todate` instead of one per company. Also in your case, you aren't actually applying any filtering with the date you obtain.

Comment: @Tole1010 Is there any way in to add a filtering condition of the date here?

Comment: You could insert the results into temp table and then join again on todate but i am not sure if that will increase your performance. It would be so much easier to help you if you provided data to populate the tables.